# Parse: How to query for a relation that contains exactly two objects?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Given two tables:

```
Users
Groups
```

One or more users can be part of a group. Each group contains a relations column with all it's users.

How can I query for a group that has an exact list of users as members in it's relation field?

I tried

```
query.whereKey(users, containsAllObjectsInArray: [userA, userB])
```

but that gives me an error

```
Unsupported query operator on relation field: users (Code: 102, Version: 1.8.5)
```

On the other hand if I use

```
query.whereKey(users, containedIn: [userA, userB])
```

I get also groups where more then the required users are members. I would then have loop through all the groups found in the first query and place another query for each group to check if the group's only members are userA + userB. That sounds too complicated.

What's the most efficient query to do this?

Comment: Can you add multiple `whereKey:@"users" equalTo:...`

Comment: That seems have the same effect as containedIn.

Comment: I don't think you can use the count, and IIRC all exact match options are array based rather than relation. I'd probably write a cloud function to make the messy under the hood requests so at least you only make 1 request from the app to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously what you want to achieve does not have a straightforward solution because Parse is designed for scalability and speed, therefore complicated pattern matching is not directly supported. The error you are getting when using `containsAllObjectsInArray` constraint happens because that constraint works on fields with `Array` type but cannot be used on `Relation` fields. To get the results you want, you need to get a bit creative. So I thought of a solution which might work using inner queries.

First, add an extra column of type `Number` to your `Group` class (lets call it 'counter') This field needs to keep the number of users who are part of a group. So every time you add a user to a group, you also increase its value by one and when you remove a user from that group, you decrease it. In your case, you can use this counter value to quickly find out which one of the groups has exactly two members.

Now you can write a query which returns the groups for which this counter is exactly two and the user Relation contains at least 'user1'. This query is going to be your inner query. Your main query now simply needs to go through what this inner query returns and selects only the records where the user relation also contains 'user2'. Given that 'having exactly two users' condition is satisfied in your inner query, you simply end up with all the group records which have exactly two users ('user1' and 'user2') in their user Relation.

```
let innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
innerQuery.whereKey("counter", equalTo: 2)  // exactly two users
innerQuery.whereKey("users", equalTo: user1) // at least user1 is there
let query = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
query.whereKey("objectId", matchesQuery: innerQuery) // exactly two users including user1
query.whereKey("users", equalTo: user2) // select groups which also have user2
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (comments: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Groups with exactly two users, user1 and user2
}
```

Comment: A counter seems to be the easiest solution. I will try to go with cloud code to update the counter. In fact The query can be simplified without an inner query by using containedIn and where counter = number of users.

Comment: As far as I know, containedIn matches your values with ANY of the elements rather than ALL of them. As you want to match users Relation with ALL of your values (given user1 & user2) then I chose the inner query method.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I meant I will do it with NSPredicate: `"users IN %@", users`. Parse offers a method for query with predicate: `PFQuery(className: predicate:)`

Comment: I would say you get the same thing as `containedIn`. I suspect you can do an exact match with `ALL` aggregate operator in `NSPredicate` but they are sadly not supported in Parse query.

Comment: Again you are right, I am actually using whereKey(equalTo:) for both users on the query to get only groups of which at least the 2 users are members.

Comment: And that didn't work either, whereKey(equalTo:) cannot be set for the same field twice. The second statement overwrites the first one. So your solution is the only working one. Thanks